# Opening the application from the background service

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have designed the app to receive text message(sms) and hence i have implemented the broadcast receiver on the background service. Everything works fine except i cant open up the application(any activity class) from the background service.
I have written a code to start an activity but that doesn't work.

I went through many similar questions, but couldn't find solution for this problem.

This is the code snippet of service class:

```
public class Background extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            String Number, Body;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

                Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                }
                for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
                    Body = new StringBuilder().append(msg.getMessageBody())
                            .toString();
                    Number = new StringBuilder().append(
                            msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()).toString();

                }
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                // "5/11/2014 03:02:10"
                String date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
                        + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                        + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":"
                        + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                MessageData db = new MessageData(getApplicationContext());
                try {

                    db.open();
                    db.createEntry(Number, Body, date, 0);
                    db.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Background.this, CallingTimer.class);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        };

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works fine

No, it does not.

You have created an instance of an anonymous inner class that inherits from `BroadcastReceiver`... and then you have done nothing with it. The instance is a local variable of your `onStartCommand()` method, and that instance will go out of scope and be garbage-collected shortly after `onStartCommand()` returns.

To fix this:

1. Move that `BroadcastReceiver` to a regular standalone `public` Java class.
2. Add a `<receiver>` element in the manifest pointing to it, with an appropriate `<intent-filter>` to receive whatever broadcasts that you think you want.
3. Add an `<activity>`, if you do not already have one, so that your receiver will start working after the user launches that activity.
4. Delete the service.
5. Do not write another service ever again, until you learn *why* you are implementing a service.